# c# save data retrieved from webservice to database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, visual-studio-2019

I would like to ask for an idea how will I saved the data I retrieved from webservice. Here is what I have so far.

Everything is working. I was able to retrieve the data I needed from webservice but I don't have idea on how will I saved the data on my database.

**cust.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using RestSharp.Authenticators;
using System.IO;
using RestSharp;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Data;

namespace SAP1
{
    class cust
    {
        public class custOutput
        {
            public string NAME;
            public string AGE;
            public string ADD;
            public DateTime DATE1;
            public DateTime DATE2;

        }

        RestClient client;
        RestRequest request;
        
        public cust()
        {
            client = new RestClient(@"http://testwebservice/");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("test1", "cust@Test1");


        }

       public List<custOutput>
        GetcustOutputs(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            request = new RestRequest("sap/bc/zcust", Method.Get);
            request.AddParameter("sap-client", "200");
            request.AddParameter("start","");
            request.AddParameter("end", end.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
            var output = client.ExecuteAsync<List<custOutput>>(request);
            var o = output.Result.Data;
            return o;


        }

        public void ProcessOutput(DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            var output = GetcustOutputs(start, end);
            Console.WriteLine(output.ToString());

          //  IEnumerable<DataRow> v = output.Select(x => new DataRow(x.NAME,));

        }

    }
}
```

This how I call my function.

**form.cs**

```
void m_oWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                _backgroundWorkerThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
                SIAP svc = new SIAP();
                
                cust cust = new cust();
                cust.ProcessOutput(dte_from.Value, dte_to.Value);
                
                
            }
            catch (ThreadAbortException)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                m_oWorker.Dispose();
                Thread.ResetAbort();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What sort of database do you have?  Is it Sql server or my sql or another relational database?  If so, you can write some code which uses sql client objects and sql to save your data

Comment: @Programnik Hi it is Microsoft SQL Server. Can you give me sample or ideas on how will I do it? Very much appreciated. Sorry for being noob. Just a newbie in c#.

Comment: I would suggest using EF Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/), the most popular ORM for .NET.